# getMultiadapter error with custom EditForm in dexterity plone 4.2

Tags: plone, dexterity

I'm trying to open a custom editform which would only show one field from a form with 12 fields:

```
class EditForm(dexterity.EditForm):
    grok.name('editCustom')
    grok.context(IInfo)

    def updateWidgets(self):
        super(EditForm, self).updateWidgets()
        self.widgets['alps'].mode = 'hidden'
        self.widgets['operationStatus'].mode = 'hidden'

# etc.
```

things work fine until I get to a field which is a MultiField list-choice:

```
        self.widgets['siteContact'].mode = 'hidden'
```

(this is the entry in the form.Schema):

```
siteContact = schema.List(
    title=_(u"Site Contact"),
    description =_(u"Select Site Contacts"),
    value_type=schema.Choice(vocabulary=("test.siteContact")),
    required=False,
)
```

but when I try to access the custom EditForm I get:

```
  Module z3c.form.widget, line 140, in render
  Module zope.component._api, line 109, in getMultiAdapter
ComponentLookupError: ((<Container at /test/first>, <HTTPRequest, URL=http://localhost:8080/test/first/@@editCustom>, <Products.Five.metaclass.EditForm object at 0x08F9D9F0>, <zope.schema._field.List object at 0x084844B0>, <OrderedSelectWidget 'form.widgets.siteContact'>), <InterfaceClass zope.pagetemplate.interfaces.IPageTemplate>, 'hidden')
```

Comment: bizarre, it seems that field types not allow it to be hidden.

Comment: bizarre indeed, i've made no progress :(

Comment: so still no progress, it seems this is just a bug, i suppose ill figure out how to report it and if i get a hotfix, ill let ya all know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the exact same problem and don't know if there's a fix or work around by now but if ordering doesn't matter, you could try `schema.Set` (or `schema.FrozenSet`) instead of `schema.List`. These all let you select multiple options. I've tested the `Set` options and they both work with the `mode` as `hidden`.

(1) Set/FrozenSet

```
field = zope.schema.Set(
   value_type=zope.schema.Choice(values=(1, 2, 3, 4)),
   default=set([1, 3]) )
widget = setupWidget(field)
widget.update()

widget.__class__
<class 'z3c.form.browser.select.SelectWidget'>
```

select widget: allows you to select one or more values from a set of given options

(2) List

```
field = zope.schema.List(
value_type=zope.schema.Choice(values=(1, 2, 3, 4)),
    default=[1, 3] )
widget = setupWidget(field)
widget.update()

widget.__class__
<class 'z3c.form.browser.orderedselect.OrderedSelectWidget'>
```

ordered-select: allows you to select one or more values from a set of given options and sort those options.

Comment: thanks for those suggestions Nick.  i've not found the work around and jumped to another part of my program (since this was a small thing).   for now ill see if these are approproate for the program!  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be specifying the vocabulary incorrectly. Please change

```
schema.Choice(vocabulary=("test.siteContact"))
```

to

```
schema.Choice(vocabulary="test.siteContact")
```

Comment: hi @vangheem, that change made no difference.  i still get the same error when i call the custom edit form.